# Publishing to redis from a linux daemon process

Tags: linux, redis, daemon, latency

I have a Linux process (written in C using hiredis library version 0.14) that periodically (~ once every 10 seconds) publishes messages to 2 Redis channels over a tcp/ip connection to a Redis server running on the same machine.

I am runnig this code on a Raspberry PI 4. It runs Raspbian with Kernel 5.10.17-v7l+. The device has 4 GB of RAM.

code for connecting to Redis is as follws:

```
struct timeval timeout = { 1, 500000 }; // 1.5 seconds 
context = redisConnectWithTimeout(REDIS_SERVER_IP, REDIS_SERVER_PORT, timeout); 

if (context == NULL || context->err) 
{ 
   if (context) 
   { 
      syslog(LOG_ERR, "REDIS connection error: %s", context->errstr); 
      redisFree(context); 
   } else { 
      syslog(LOG_ERR,"Unable to allocate REDIS context."); 
   } 
   return FAILURE; 
}
```

Code for publishing is as follows:

```
if (!msg || !channel_name) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    redisReply* reply = (redisReply*) redisCommand(context, "PUBLISH %s %s", channel_name, msg);

    if (reply) {
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Published on channel %s of REDIS.", channel_name);
        freeReplyObject(reply);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    switch(context->err) {
        case REDIS_ERR_IO:
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "There was an I/O error while connecting to REDIS.");
            break;
        case REDIS_ERR_EOF:
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "REDIS server closed the connection.");
            break;
        case REDIS_ERR_PROTOCOL:
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "REDIS protocol error.");
            break;
        case REDIS_ERR_OTHER:
        default:
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "Unknown REDIS Error.");
            break;
    }

    return context->err;
```

Sytemd unit file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Service
After=systemd-timesyncd.service
Requires=systemd-timesyncd.service
#StartLimitIntervalSec=0
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=10

[Service]
Type=forking
# instructions at https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
User=root
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
ControlGroup=cpu:/
# TODO Before Deploying - Change GPS Data file location accordingly and uncomment the following line
ExecStart=/home/pi/source/someapp


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run this as a process, I see the published messages are instantaneously available on Redis (seen using redis-cli). On the other hand, when I run the process as a systemctl daemon, there is a significant amount of delay (order of several minutes) before the messages are pushed to the subscribers. What is the reason for this latency? Is it because these processes are running with low priority? If so, how to fix this? please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Please show a minimal complete example of the code that behaves like this - along with how it is started in `systemctl` and which platform and OS version you are using. At the moment we can't even tell what language bindings you are using.

Comment: Thank you! As per your suggestion, I have added the details.

Comment: Do you remain connected to Redis between publishing messages, or reconnect each time? You appear to write to the syslog after receiving the reply from Redis, so can you tell if the delay happens while waiting for the reply from Redis or if Redis replies immediately but then takes a long time to actually publish? Have you tried putting the Redis server on a different machine? How busy is the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Application remains connected. Does not reconnect. The log messages show the messages have been published. However, no messages appear on redis-cli. Furthermore, I used tcpdump (sudo tcpdump -v -i lo dst port 6379) to see the messages are being sent from the app to redis  server.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a standalone device. Cannot add any other machine. RPI is busy (about 60% load on all the 4 cores). Load is in the same ballpark whether the application is running as a foreground process or as a daemon.